# How to show an additional column from CSV file as a tooltip in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, heatmap

I want to display not only the X/Y values for the graph (in my case the year and the temperature anomaly), but one additional piece of information (i.e. one column) from the CSV file.

That is, I have this Highcharts heat map

[image]

and would like to display the RANK in the tooltip as indicated in the CSV:

```
Year,Y,Temperature Anomaly,Rank
1880,1,-0.12,91
1881,1,-0.09,83
1882,1,-0.1,86
1883,1,-0.18,103
```

Is that possible? If yes, how? I couldn't find any information on this.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/e7f3Lqgb/3/) is a fiddle.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `seriesMapping` property to add extra data and display it in a tooltip through `tooltip.formatter` function:

```
    data: {
        ...,
        seriesMapping: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 1,
            value: 2,
            rank: 3
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Year: ' + this.point.x + ' ' + 
              '<br /><b>Temp. Anomaly: ' + this.point.value + 
              ' °C </b><br />Rank: ' + this.point.rank;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/owqc3pjk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Comment: Wow, cool! Thanks a lot. However, it returns a »TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a[f.columnIndex][c]')« [in my case](https://graphs-test.unepgrid.ch/graph_global_temperature_heatmap_2.php). No idea why. Should be everything the same as in your code. It doesn't like the »rank: 3« addition in »seriesMapping«. Do you have any idea? Grrrr...

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, Could you reproduce that case in jsfiddle?

Comment: No idea how to reproduce it in jsfiddle, as I would have said that it's really the same thing. Copy-paste of your piece of code (seriesMapping), and same CSV data. I have no clue. When I delete »rank: 3« in »seriesMapping« it works fine. But as soon as I add that line, it spits out the error.

Comment: There must be some difference. Please try to use not minified Highcharts code and debug what causes the problem.